# Socket io join room in distributed architecture

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Its easy to (join) room when clients are connected to one socket io server.

But if i have distributed socket io server in one datacenter where two clients or connected to two separate socket io server.

How do i add them into room (join) so that they can communicate

```
Socket Server-01        Socket Server-02
      ^                        ^
      |                        |
      |                        |
      v                        v
   Client-01               Client-02
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a socket.io adapter such as [socket.io-redis](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis) will allow you to do this.

> By running socket.io with the socket.io-redis adapter you can run
>   multiple socket.io instances in different processes or servers that
>   can all broadcast and emit events to and from each other.

Once you have setup the adapter on each of your socket.io nodes, it will just work, no further changes to your code required.

I personally like to use [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis) rather than the default [node_redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis), as I find it more reliable.

```
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redisAdapter = require('socket.io-ioredis');
var io = require('socket.io')();

io.adapter(redisAdapter({
  pubClient: new Redis('redis://:authpassword@127.0.0.1:6380/4'),
  subClient: new Redis('redis://:authpassword@127.0.0.1:6380/4'),
}));

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  // do your thing.
});
```